# Is there a way to turn off identity increment in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

By accident I made a column that wasn't null friendly, even though I saw an error I tried a few times to add a null; didn't work.

But now my `ID_Phisical` that was my primary key is now, well weird. Do I have to create a new table or is there a way to just revert it back to 1 instead of 20?

[image]

Comment: `TRUNCATE` also resets the identity seed (and also removes all data from the table)

Comment: The value of your identity shouldn't matter. If it matters then you probably shouldn't be using an identity.  I would also suggest you spell Physical correctly or it will drive you nuts. And NEVER store the age of a person unless it is for historical purposes (like their age at the last visit or similar). Instead store the birthdate and calculate age when needed.

Comment: Your `IDENTITY` isn't "weird", it's working as intended. The value of the `IDENTITY` is incremented every time you attempt to `INSERT` a row, it doesn't matter if that `INSERT` fails. You attempted to `INSERT` multiple rows that failed your constraints (for the column to not be `NULL`) and so the row wasn't inserted, but the `IDENTITY` value was still used, as it was supposed to be. Nothing weird at all. In fact, it would be weird if the value of your `IDENTITY` didn't skip the values for the failed `INSERT` statements.

Answer (score 0):

For change reset identity, use command

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[TestTable]', RESEED, 0);
```